# Random colors by default in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I had a look at Kaggle's [univariate-plotting-with-pandas](https://www.kaggle.com/residentmario/univariate-plotting-with-pandas). There's this line which generates bar graph.

`reviews['province'].value_counts().head(10).plot.bar()`

I don't see any color scheme defined specifically. 
I tried plotting it using `jupyter notebook` but could see only one color instead of all multiple colors as at Kaggle.

I tried reading the document and online help but couldn't get any method to generate these colors just by the line above.

How do we do that? Is there a config to set this randomness by default?

[image: At Kaggle:]

[image: Jupyter Notebook:]

Comment: for the record, these "random" colours are the default matplotlib [colormap](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) - see "tab10" under "Qualitative colormaps"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the multicoloured bars were the default behaviour in one of the former `pandas` versions and Kaggle must have used that one for their tutorial (you can read more [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20585)).

You can easily recreate the plot by defining a list of standard colours and then using it as an argument in `bar`.

```
colors = ['#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e', '#2ca02c', '#d62728', '#9467bd',
          '#8c564b', '#e377c2', '#7f7f7f', '#bcbd22', '#17becf']
reviews['province'].value_counts().head(10).plot.bar(color=colors)
```

[image]

Tested on `pandas 0.24.1` and `matplotlib 2.2.2`.

Answer (score 4):

In seaborn is it not problem:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.countplot(x='province', data=reviews)
```

In matplotlib are not spaces, but possible with convert values to one row DataFrame:

```
reviews['province'].value_counts().head(10).to_frame(0).T.plot.bar()
```

Or use some [qualitative colormap](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#qualitative):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 10
reviews['province'].value_counts().head(N).plot.bar(color=plt.cm.Paired(np.arange(N)))
```

---

```
reviews['province'].value_counts().head(N).plot.bar(color=plt.cm.Pastel1(np.arange(N)))
```

Answer (score 4):

The colorful plot has been produced with an earlier version of pandas (<= 0.23). Since then, pandas has decided to make bar plots monochrome, because the color of the bars is pretty meaningless. If you still want to produce a bar chart with the default colors from the "tab10" colormap in pandas >= 0.24, and hence recreate the previous behaviour, it would look like

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 13
df = pd.Series(np.random.randint(10,50,N), index=np.arange(1,N+1))

cmap = plt.cm.tab10
colors = cmap(np.arange(len(df)) % cmap.N)
df.plot.bar(color=colors)

plt.show()
```

[image]